# Efficiently iterating through multiple lists (GPS coordinates)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a programme which takes a gpx file (xml document containing a list of time, latitude, longitude etc) and identifies whether coordinates within a lookup table have been passed. I'm currently achieving this by calculating the distance between every point in the GPX file against every point in the lookup list. For any point that has a distance within a certain range, I return the point that has been passed.

For reference: Each GPX file contains ~5000 points which need to be compared against ~200 coordinates in the lookup file. The lookup file is a csv which is imported as a dictionary and the GPS file is imported as a GPS object containing a list of point objects (tuples of lat, lon).

I've succeeded in achieving this, and am now in the process of optimising it for performance. I've optimised the maths of calculating the distance (approximating for flat earth, pre-calculating cosines etc) but I'm not sure how to optimise comparing every element in a list with another list.

Below is my code snippet, as you can see, one of the things I'm doing is iterating through all GPS coordinates for every 1 lookup row. On reaching a point whose distance is below 50m from the lookup point, I'm breaking the for loop and moving to the next lookup point. This has brought my total execution time down to ~0.3s, though I feel like there is likely a more efficient way of doing this even faster but so far I've had no luck

```
for row in gps_lookup:
   cos_factor = math.cos(row['lat1'])                                           
   for gps_point in points:
       delta_y = 12430 * (gps_point.latitude - row['lat1'])/180
       delta_x = (24901 * (gps_point.longitude - row['lon1'])/360) * cos_factor
       dist = math.sqrt(delta_x * delta_x + delta_y * delta_y)                             
       if dist < 0.05:                                                                     
           print(row['Point name'])
           break
```

Does anyone know of possibly speedier ways of achieving this? Things that spring to mind are 'if the distance of the point is greater than 1000m, don't bother checking the distance of the next 10 points because they're probably too far away as well'. I'm happy to keep plugging away at trying to identify some more rule based optimisations, but I don't know whether looping within a loop is the most sensible approach, and whether there are other methods to achieve this?